# Unreal Engine HTC Vive Controller Setup

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new to unreal engine, I have purchased HTC Vive, I want to setup motion controllers with custom 3D Objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Proper Documentation on how to setup motion controller on epic games site. Check following link.

[enter link description here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/MotionController/)

Answer (score 1):

I would start [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/index.html), with Epic's general overview of VR development, and then depending on what you're interested in doing, you may find it worthwhile to look at Mordentral's [VR Expansion Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/mordentral/vrexpansionplugin/overview). It's well-written and provides solutions for lots of things you might want to do in room-scale VR.